# Ternary Relation - How to code it in SQL Server ? +derived attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I have 3 tables which are in a ternary relation (1:1:N) in my ER-Model.

To transfer it into SQL-Server, I assume I need to add another table to it. But I'm not so sure how to do it.

Code:

```
create table[buyer]   --1 in the relation
(id int primary key)

create table[payment] --1 in the relation
(id int primary key)

create table[product] --n in the relation
(id int primary key,)

create table[connecting_tab]
(
id1 int constraint fk_buyer foreign key references buyer(id),
id2 int constraint fk_payment foreign key references payment(id),
id3 int constraint fk_product foreign key references product(id),    
)
```

Relation is described in the modell as "buys".

Will this build a ternary relation in the sql server?
How can I define that the relation 1:1:N - what is the relation of the connecting_tab to buyer-, payment- and product-tab? (1:1, 1:N or N:N)

Also: there is a derived attribute detached to the relation-symbol in the middle (→ ER-Model). Do I write it in the connecting_table:

```
  create table [connecting_tab]
  (...
   attr int NOT NULL --derived attribute
  )
```

or how should I define the derived attribute?

Answer (score 0):

A perfectly natural way to model this would seem to be:

```
create table purchases (
    buyer_id int constraint fk_buyer foreign key references buyer(id),
    payment_id int constraint fk_payment foreign key references payment(id),
    product_id constraint fk_product foreign key references product(id), 
    final_price decimal(10, 4)   
);
```

Although this models your diagram, it seems strange.  I am more used to situations where product purchases are in tables called something like `OrderLines`, these are tied to `Orders`, and `Orders` have a key linking to `Customers`.  `Customers` (and perhaps orders) are then tied to `Payments`.

That may not be true in your case.  If someone purchases a single product at a time with a single method of payment, then I think I would expect the "payment" attributes to be in the `purchases` table.

Comment: is the "Purchases"-table the connecting-table?                                                    my posted modell is just a small part of a bigger ER-modell, also buyer is described as "user". in my task the user can log in to a shop where you can buy products.

Comment: is the relation in your posted code a 1:1:N-relation? OR does the relation from two tables to the connecting_table has to be 1:1 and i have to declarify that additonal? If yes, how do i declare that it's a 1:1-relation. or is the relation from 2 tables a 1:N-relation and 1 table a N:M relation? Do i need than another table?

Answer (score 0):

Your `connecting_tab` should be called `Orders`, but there's more here than just that.

Order itself is rarely atomic; rather, it is usually a master-detail of (at least) two tables:

```
create table dbo.Orders (
  Id int primary key,
  BuyerId int foreign key references dbo.Buyers(Id)
);
go
create table dbo.OrderDetails (
  OrderId int foreign key references dbo.Orders(Id),
  ProductId int foreign key references dbo.Products(Id),
  Price money not null,
  Amount int not null default (1),
  primary key (OrderId, ProductId)
);
go
```

Payments are rather orthogonal to this table, actually. When I buy at somewhere like Amazon, it's not at all uncommon to place, say, 7 orders and have only 3 withdrawals from my credit card. So, unless being forced to do so, I wouldn't link orders with payments at all. Instead, I would put a running balance column into the `Payments` table, which would show this buyer's balance at the moment of this payment, including the payment itself.

Of course, this doesn't preclude you from linking buyers with payments 1:N - in most systems I've worked on, anonymous payments were not allowed.

Comment: So in the task i got from my prof it's an university-canteen. an there's an app, where you can log in and preorder or inform yourself about different stuff to eat.                                                                                                          in which relation stands the new table i created (Orders) in relation to the other table, when the relation in the ternary relation was a one-to-one-to-many-relation? is it one-to-one,one-to-one and many-to-one OR many-to-many, one-to-many and one-to many?

Comment: You don't really understand the stuff, don't you? Okay, every `foreign key` designates a 1:N relationship between referenced (parent) and referencing (child) tables. So, if we are talking on conceptual / logical level, `Orders` is a child (N side in 1:N) to `Buyers`. However, it is related N:N to `Products`, since one product can be referenced in many orders, and vice versa. Here, the `OrderDetails` table is a crosstab between orders and products, but conceptually it is a part of the `Orders` entity.

Comment: Regarding this "ternary relation": I never saw this term used in business environment. It is too academic, and besides, the whole idea falls apart without order in which entities are mentioned that everybody has agreed upon, so saying `N:1:N` alone makes no sense. If you need to talk the same language with your prof, it's better to ask elsewhere, sorry.